# Get out the information from the function

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can i get out the information from the function? Because when i start the file into the terminal, the

```
console.log(latitude1 + " " + longitude1);
```

return me "undefined", instead when i put the

```
 console.log(latitude1 + " " + longitude1);
```

in the function, returns me the longitue and the latitude.

```
var triangulate = require('wifi-triangulate')

var latitude1;
var longitude1;

triangulate(function (err, location) {
  //if (err) throw err
  var latitude = location.lat;
  var longitude = location.lng;
  latitude1 = latitude;
  longitude1 = longitude;
});
  console.log(latitude1 + " " + longitude1);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Comment: Well, you have just discovered that js is async!

Comment: @Teemu Well, that won't work since the function is a callback function

Comment: how can I keep it from being callback?

Comment: @Edoard0s The thing is, you can't make node work that way. Because `triangulate` is an async function and node does not wait for an async function to finish before executing the next code. The callback is still required if you want to get the result of an async function. There are other way tho, such as `Promise`.

Comment: The problem is that i don't know how i can use the longitude and latitude of the function elsewhere

Comment: You can put it to DB if You want. Or call another function from inside of triangulate function. or use async library to chain waterfall call

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just run asynchronous (non-blocking) function and after function check for result.

Because JS does not wait (does not block execution) when `triangulate` function will finish and go to next line.

For newbies I'll tell that it's something like ajax call in jquery.

Check this example:

```
var async = require('async');
var triangulate = require('wifi-triangulate');

function doSomethingWithLocation(location, cb) {
  console.log(location);
  // save to db and etc operations here
  cb();
}

async.waterfall([
  triangulate,
  doSomethingWithLocation
]);

console.log('Here goes triangulate result:'); // while `triangulate` will work, it will output message before that triangulate will pass result to `doSomethingWithLocation`
```

If You want to continuously get location data and operate on it, checkout this example:

1) We create component called location and put our desired functionality inside of it

components/location.js:

```
var triangulate = require('wifi-triangulate');

module.exports = function(callback) {
  triangulate(function(err, location) {
    if(err) {
      console.error(err);
      return callback({});
    }

    callback(location);
  });
}
```

2) In app file we require this component and use it and 
app.js:

```
var async = require('async');
var getLocation = require('./components/location');

var latitude, longitude;

function handleLocation(lat, lon) {
  console.log('Got location information:', lat, lon);

  // You can add here db query to update/insert info to db
}


getLocation(function(data) {
  latitude = data.lat;
  longitude = data.lng;
  handleLocation(latitude, longitude);
});

console.log('You cannot see lat, lon', latitude, longitude);
console.log('Because You\'ve to wait for execution of getLocation to complete');
```

Comment: If i want to save the data of "location" in an external variable to use in an another file, how can i do?

Comment: it's not php or something similar, You cannot just directly pass it to variable in another function, module and etc, seems like You're newbie, so You do not understand logic of non-blocking and also how in nodejs modules are built.

Comment: @Edoard0s if You don't understand how js's non-blocking things work and don't understand how nodejs requires another modules, may be You switch to some another technologies, go, python, ruby, java and so on...

Comment: Ok i get it, but i need to save latitude and longitude into two variables, do you know others methods using node or only javascript, but without asking permission of geolocation?

Comment: I've put an example where it gets information and puts to variable.

Comment: Error: Cannot find module './components/location'

Comment: Create folder components and create file location.js and put the code there

Comment: ReferenceError: ds is not defined

Comment: Sorry, my fault, remove ds.set line in location.js

Comment: I don't understand...i remove it...  ReferenceError: ds is not defined

Comment: if it says ds is not defined so in location.js there is a line ds.set... find it, remove those line and run app again

Comment: /Users/Administrator/Desktop/Mirror/Config/components/location.js:10
    ds.set('location', location); There's no more

Comment: callback(location); Only

Comment: ReferenceError: ds is not defined
    at /Users/Administrator/Desktop/Mirror/Config/components/location.js:10:5
    at f (/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Mirror/node_modules/once/once.js:17:25)
    at processBody (/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Mirror/node_modules/geocode-wifi/index.js:10:3)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Mirror/node_modules/geocode-wifi/index.js:50:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)

Comment: at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:934:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

Comment: open /Users/Administrator/Desktop/Mirror/Config/components/locati‌​on.js again, remove the line and SAVE it and rerun the app (:

Comment: Excuse me, I had two identical files, thanks! Now how can i export the data in the variables : latitude, longitude to use in an other file?

Comment: yes! I've also exported it to global variable. please don't ask more questions, You've not any normal experience with JS, especially nodejs and that's why You don't understand my code or other's examples. 
ask another guy, maybe he is more "mentorish".

Answer (score 1):

`triangulate` package written in callback style, you can convert it to async, or use as it is

### callback

```
var triangulate = require('wifi-triangulate')

function myTriangulate(callback) {
  triangulate(function (err, location) {
    if (err) throw err;
    callback(location);
  });
}

myTriangulate(function(loc) {
  console.log(loc.latitude + " " + loc.longitude); 
});
```

### async

```
var triangulate = require('wifi-triangulate')
//use default node's promise lib
//or similar libs like bluebird

function myTriangulate() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    triangulate(function (err, location) {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      resolve(location);
    });
  }); 
}

myTriangulate().then(function(loc) {
  console.log(loc.latitude + " " + loc.longitude); 
});
```